# Connect to MS Access Database from Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I can't really find anything online about how to do this.
There are a few separate, offline, Microsoft Databases existing...

Everyone has begun staging different .accdb files in an Amazon S3 bucket - I'm hoping Snowflake now provides an easy (ish) solution to reading them into the SQL database I'm building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. Snowflake can import text files in various formats (csv, XML, JSON, etc) but is has no extract capabilities so it can't connect to applications and read data from them: asking it to read a MS Access file is no different from asking it to read an Oracle or SQL Server file.

You probably have 2 options:

1. Export the data from MS Access to a file format that Snowflake
   can ingest
2. Use an ETL tool that can read from MS Access and
   write to S3 as text files (or directly to Snowflake, which is
   probably simpler

Comment: I'm going the python route. There are some out of the box solutions that actually seem to work, but they seem to require me downloading the files locally from the S3 to do the job

Comment: That's right - you need some kind of MDB aware "compute" in order to import access files. Here's some source that looks like it does this... but it doesn't, it still needs an Ec2 to do the work. https://github.com/eilst/mdb-to-csv-s3-lambda-ec2

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to connect to Snowflake in Microsoft Access through an ODBC connection. You first need to install the [Snowflake ODBC Driver](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc.html) and configure a DSN.

Comment: Does this require having MS access installed? I'm looking to just read the .accdb files from an S3